using Time.h , mktime() returns wrong date
Using this code:
struct tm nsr;
struct tm ssr ; 
  
nsr.tm_hour = 6; 
nsr.tm_min = 8; 
nsr.tm_sec = 46;
nsr.tm_mday = 29;
nsr.tm_mon = 2; 
nsr.tm_year = 2024;
mktime(&nsr); 

ssr = nsr; 
ssr.tm_sec +=186600;
mktime(&ssr);

printf ( "%02d:%02d:%02d\n", ssr.tm_hour, ssr.tm_min, ssr.tm_sec); 
printf ( "%02d:%02d:%02d\n", ssr.tm_mday, ssr.tm_mon, ssr.tm_year); 

Outputs:
09:58:46
31:02:2024

What could be wrong here. If add lesser value to tm_sec, with the date, it gives correct time.
Shouln't the date roll over to march correctly ?

Unrelated: Why not use std::chrono::system_clock?

That mix of code and text won't compile, so you're asking folks to do a lot of work to try to figure out what your code actually does. Fix it: post the smallest code you can come up with that compiles, runs, and shows the problem

@TedLyngmo Usually ignorance or masochism.


shouln't the date roll over to march correctly?

It is already in March since tm_mon is zero based.
Also note that tm_year is supposed to contain Years since 1900.
Change to:
nsr.tm_mon = 1; // Feb.
nsr.tm_year = 2024 - 1900;

And:
std::printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", ssr.tm_mday, ssr.tm_mon + 1, ssr.tm_year + 1900);
//                                                      ^^^              ^^^^^^

You also need initialize the struct when creating it and set tm_isdst to -1 to make mktime try to figure out if DST is in effect or not:
std::tm nsr{}; // zero all fields
nsr.tm_isdst = -1;

If you are using C++11 or later, I recommend that you use std::chrono instead. It simplifies things a lot and it's a lot harder get a program to compile with the kind of errors you have in your current code.

Pete Becker, It compiles , see the output .

@Suresh Did you get it to succeed following what I wrote in the answer?

Ted Lyngmo , I shall check and report back. I am new to this forum and just about understanding its functionality. so pls excuse me.

@Suresh No worries. Just ask for clarifications if there's anything in the answer that you think needs it.
